# Simply: How to paint a DropDown for a ComboBox

Tags: visual-c++, combobox, dropdown

This should not be this hard. I have searched and cannot find hints on how to paint the dropdown for a combobox control in a Dialog Box created with the VS2022 resource editor. The dialog and specifically the ComboBox control works but the visual is not good. The dropdown has one line for the current selection when I'd like it to show all four selections. I can choose the option by using the up and down arrows but a mouse is useless.
[image: One line for four selections]

Right now, supporting code in the dialog procedure only processes the WM_INITDIALOG, WM_COMMAND CBN_SELCHANGE, WM_COMMAND CBN_DROPDOWN messages. I'm pretty sure there should be something in that last process and pretty sure there should be a WM_PAINT but I don't understand what's needed.

`BOOL CALLBACK GedcomDlgProc( HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{

```
static bool lFirst, lDone;
HWND    hClutter, hClutterMin, hClutterMax;
COMBOBOXINFO    info = { sizeof( COMBOBOXINFO ) };
DRAWITEMSTRUCT* DIS;
int     i, sel;
WCHAR   txt[128];

switch ( msg )
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    // <Some Housekeeping>
    OptionsDlgSets( hDlg );
    hClutter = GetDlgItem( hDlg, IDC_CLUTTER );
    SendMessage( hClutter, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"0 - Critical Only" );
    SendMessage( hClutter, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"1 - Edit Family Members" );
    SendMessage( hClutter, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"2 - Edit Direct Relatives" );
    SendMessage( hClutter, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)L"3 - Edit All Individuals" );
    SendMessage( hClutter, CB_SETCURSEL, 2, (LPARAM)0 );
    // <More Housekeeping>
    return false;

case WM_COMMAND:
    lDone = FALSE;
    switch ( HIWORD( wParam ) )
    {
    case CBN_SELCHANGE:
        sel = SendMessage( (HWND)lParam, CB_GETCURSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0 );
        memset( &txt, 0, sizeof( txt ) );
        i = SendMessage( (HWND)lParam, CB_GETLBTEXT, (WPARAM)sel, (LPARAM)txt );
        txt[i] = 0;
        gOptions.setnClutter( stoi( txt ) );
        lDone = true; break;

    case CBN_DROPDOWN:
        if ( LOWORD( wParam ) == IDC_CLUTTER ) {
            hClutter = GetDlgItem( hDlg, IDC_CLUTTER );
            info.cbSize = sizeof( COMBOBOXINFO );
            GetComboBoxInfo( hClutter, &info );
        } // endif
        lDone = true; break;

    } // endswitch
    if ( !lDone ) {
        // <Other Controls>
    } // endif
    OptionsDlgSets( hDlg );
    return true;

} // endswitch
return false;
```

} // endfunc GedcomDlgProc

I've played with the Properties for the control but didn't find anything that would make it display all four choices. Do I need to send and process a WM_PAINT message from some notification procedure? What specifically needs to be done there? Does someone have an example?

Comment: In the dialog editor, resize the drop-down control to the size you want it to have when the drop-down list is opened. In other words, include the space for the list in the control's size.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Much simpler than I envisioned.  Thank you.  It works now.